# Debugging AngularJs, how to locate the error

Tags: angularjs, debugging

I have an Angular application that I have been asked to refactor.

The files are very large and when I make a typo I get an error similar to below, which doesn't really tell me much other than the file for the LiveServiceProvider won't parse. (In this example I had a factory with a mistake in the camel-casing of a variable).

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: LiveProfilesServiceProvider <- LiveProfilesService <- LiveDeliveryProfilesController <- LiveDeliveryProfilesController
```

Is there a way to find out what part of the file is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way than to undertstand from console messages.

You are injecting `LiveProfilesService` into  `LiveDeliveryProfilesController` controller, but AngularJs cant find `LiveProfilesService`.

Reason:

1. Service name (`LiveProfilesService`) that you are injecting is incorrect, OR
2. Service JS file has not been included in html file.

You wont get such detailed error on `angular.min.js` files so use minified ones in production only.

Comment: Yes, I understand the error, I was hoping that there would be a way to find the line where I had made the typo. The files are large so its a really slow process trying to locate them.